# How to add hover effect to product images on bigcartel "neat" theme

Tags: html, css, hover, bigcartel

I'd like to create a hover effect on my product images that flicks to a second image like this:

```
.product-img-wrapper img:last-of-type {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

What do I need to add to my code and whereabouts should I put it? I'm using bigcartel's "Neat" theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is the initial state. Not sure what you want to happen when hovered. Let's assume you want the hovered state of the image to be visible. The code would be:

```
.product-img-wrapper img:last-of-type:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```